# How to access pixels in Opengl?

Tags: c++, opengl, pixel

I'm trying to collect all pixels color, than change same color and at the end render!

I searched for that and the results are:
`glReadPixels()` and `glDrawPixels()`, `glReadPixels()` works fine but `glDrawPixels()` not!

The problem is I have info in the array filled by `glReadPixels` but how can I pass this to OpenGL for render?

I tried to use `glDrawPixels()` but it doesn't work, neither with an array filled with red color (1,0,0);

```
do{

        int size = 1024*768*3;
        std::vector<GLfloat> pixel(size); 
        for (int i = 0; i< size; i+=3)
            pixel[i] = 1.0;
        glWritePixels(1024, 768, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, &pixel[0]);

        // Swap buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();

    } // Check if the ESC key was pressed or the window was closed
    while( glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE ) != GLFW_PRESS &&
           glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0 );
```

So searching again, and I found a tutorial on how render on a texture:

```
// Include standard headers
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>
// Include GLEW
#include <glew.h>

// Include GLFW
#include <glfw3.h>
GLFWwindow* window;

// Include GLM
#include <glm.hpp>
#include <gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
using namespace glm;

#include "shader.hpp"

int main( void )
{
    // Initialise GLFW
    if( !glfwInit() )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n" );
        return -1;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);


    // Open a window and create its OpenGL context
    window = glfwCreateWindow( 1024, 768, "Cube", NULL, NULL);
    if( window == NULL ){
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window. If you have an Intel GPU, they are not 3.3 compatible. Try the 2.1 version of the tutorials.\n" );
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // Initialize GLEW
    glewExperimental = true; // Needed for core profile
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Ensure we can capture the escape key being pressed below
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);

    // Dark blue background
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);

    // Enable depth test
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    // Accept fragment if it closer to the camera than the former one
    //glDepthFunc(GL_LESS); 

    GLuint VertexArrayID;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
    glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);

    // Create and compile our GLSL program from the shaders
    GLuint programID = LoadShaders( "TransformVertexShader.vertexshader", "ColorFragmentShader.fragmentshader" );

    // Get a handle for our "MVP" uniform
    GLuint MatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "MVP");

    // Projection matrix : 45° Field of View, 4:3 ratio, display range : 0.1 unit <-> 100 units
    glm::mat4 Projection = glm::perspective(45.0f, 4.0f / 3.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    // Camera matrix
    glm::mat4 View       = glm::lookAt(
                                glm::vec3(4,3,-3), // Camera is at (4,3,-3), in World Space
                                glm::vec3(0,0,0), // and looks at the origin
                                glm::vec3(0,1,0)  // Head is up (set to 0,-1,0 to look upside-down)
                           );
    // Model matrix : an identity matrix (model will be at the origin)
    glm::mat4 Model      = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    // Our ModelViewProjection : multiplication of our 3 matrices
    glm::mat4 MVP        = Projection * View * Model; // Remember, matrix multiplication is the other way around

    // Our vertices. Tree consecutive floats give a 3D vertex; Three consecutive vertices give a triangle.
    // A cube has 6 faces with 2 triangles each, so this makes 6*2=12 triangles, and 12*3 vertices
    static const GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] = { 
        -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
         1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
         1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
         1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
         1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
         1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
         1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
         1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
         1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
         1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f
    };

    // One color for each vertex. They were generated randomly.
    static const GLfloat g_color_buffer_data[] = { 
        0.583f,  0.771f,  0.014f,
                0.583f,  0.771f,  0.014f,
                0.583f,  0.771f,  0.014f,
                0.583f,  0.771f,  0.014f,
                0.583f,  0.771f,  0.014f,
                0.583f,  0.771f,  0.014f,
                0.583f,  0.771f,  0.014f,
                0.583f,  0.771f,  0.014f,
                0.583f,  0.771f,  0.014f,
                0.583f,  0.771f,  0.014f,
                0.583f,  0.771f,  0.014f,
                0.583f,  0.771f,  0.014f,
                0.583f,  0.771f,  0.014f,
                0.583f,  0.771f,  0.014f,
                0.583f,  0.771f,  0.014f,
                0.583f,  0.771f,  0.014f,
                0.583f,  0.771f,  0.014f,
                0.583f,  0.771f,  0.014f,
                0.583f,  0.771f,  0.014f,
                0.583f,  0.771f,  0.014f,
                0.583f,  0.771f,  0.014f,
                0.583f,  0.771f,  0.014f,
                0.583f,  0.771f,  0.014f,
                0.583f,  0.771f,  0.014f,
                0.583f,  0.771f,  0.014f,
                0.583f,  0.771f,  0.014f,
                0.583f,  0.771f,  0.014f,
                0.583f,  0.771f,  0.014f,
                0.583f,  0.771f,  0.014f,
                0.583f,  0.771f,  0.014f,
                0.583f,  0.771f,  0.014f,
                0.583f,  0.771f,  0.014f,
                0.583f,  0.771f,  0.014f,
                0.583f,  0.771f,  0.014f,
                0.583f,  0.771f,  0.014f,
                0.583f,  0.771f,  0.014f
    };

    GLuint vertexbuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data), g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLuint colorbuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &colorbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_color_buffer_data), g_color_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glUseProgram(programID);


        // ---------------------------------------------
    // Render to Texture - specific code begins here
    // ---------------------------------------------

    // The framebuffer, which regroups 0, 1, or more textures, and 0 or 1 depth buffer.
    GLuint FramebufferName = 0;
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &FramebufferName);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FramebufferName);

    // The texture we're going to render to
    GLuint renderedTexture;
    glGenTextures(1, &renderedTexture);

    // "Bind" the newly created texture : all future texture functions will modify this texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderedTexture);

    // Give an empty image to OpenGL ( the last "0" means "empty" )
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,GL_RGB, 1024, 768, 0,GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

    // Poor filtering
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST); 
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    // The depth buffer
    GLuint depthrenderbuffer;
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthrenderbuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthrenderbuffer);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, 1024, 768);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthrenderbuffer);

    //----------------------------

    // Set "renderedTexture" as our colour attachement #0
    glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, renderedTexture, 0);

    // Set the list of draw buffers.
    GLenum DrawBuffers[1] = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0};
    glDrawBuffers(1, DrawBuffers); // "1" is the size of DrawBuffers

    // Always check that our framebuffer is ok
    if(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    {
        printf("\nFrameBuffer Error\n");
        return false;
    }


    // The fullscreen quad's FBO
    static const GLfloat g_quad_vertex_buffer_data[] = { 
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
         1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
         1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
         1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
    };

    GLuint quad_vertexbuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &quad_vertexbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, quad_vertexbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_quad_vertex_buffer_data), g_quad_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Create and compile our GLSL program from the shaders
    GLuint quad_programID = LoadShaders( "Passthrough.vertexshader", "WobblyTexture.fragmentshader" );
    GLuint texID = glGetUniformLocation(quad_programID, "renderedTexture");


    do{




        // Render to our framebuffer
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FramebufferName);
        glViewport(0,0,1024,768); // Render on the whole framebuffer, complete from the lower left corner to the upper right

        // Clear the screen
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Use our shader
        glUseProgram(programID);

        // Send our transformation to the currently bound shader, 
        // in the "MVP" uniform
        glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);

        // 1rst attribute buffer : vertices
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(
            0,                  // attribute. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
            3,                  // size
            GL_FLOAT,           // type
            GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
            0,                  // stride
            (void*)0            // array buffer offset
        );

        // 2nd attribute buffer : colors
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorbuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(
            1,                                // attribute. No particular reason for 1, but must match the layout in the shader.
            3,                                // size
            GL_FLOAT,                         // type
            GL_FALSE,                         // normalized?
            0,                                // stride
            (void*)0                          // array buffer offset
        );

        // Draw the triangle !
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 12*3); // 12*3 indices starting at 0 -> 12 triangles

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);



        // Render to the screen
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
        glViewport(0,0,1024,768); // Render on the whole framebuffer, complete from the lower left corner to the upper right

        // Clear the screen
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Use our shader
        glUseProgram(quad_programID);


        // Bind our texture in Texture Unit 0
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderedTexture);
        // Set our "renderedTexture" sampler to user Texture Unit 0
        glUniform1i(texID, 0);

        // 1rst attribute buffer : vertices
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, quad_vertexbuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(
            0,                  // attribute 0. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
            3,                  // size
            GL_FLOAT,           // type
            GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
            0,                  // stride
            (void*)0            // array buffer offset
        );


        // Draw the triangles !
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6); // 2*3 indices starting at 0 -> 2 triangles

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);



        // Swap buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();

    } // Check if the ESC key was pressed or the window was closed
    while( glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE ) != GLFW_PRESS &&
           glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0 );

        // Cleanup VBO and shader
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &colorbuffer);
    glDeleteProgram(programID);


    glDeleteFramebuffers(1, &FramebufferName);
    glDeleteTextures(1, &renderedTexture);
    glDeleteRenderbuffers(1, &depthrenderbuffer);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &quad_vertexbuffer);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);

    // Close OpenGL window and terminate GLFW
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

But again I don't know how access to pixels before render them on screen, in the previous example I think all data are store in `FrameBufferName` variable, but how can I access to this buffer and take all the pixels color data?

Comment: `glDrawPixels (...)` will not work in a core context profile. It draws pixels beginning at the current raster position, and the entire notion of a raster position was removed as was `glDrawPixels (...)`. The closest analog that exists in modern OpenGL is `glBlitFramebuffer (...)`.

Comment: If you really need `glDrawPixels (...)` you can always go with a compatibility profile (on most platforms anyway).

Comment: Thanks, I'll search all about `glBlitFramebuffer(...)`, I don't want to use `glDrawPixels(...)` because now I know it is cancelled.